# How to use custom URL Schemes IOS Objective-c PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, safari, url-scheme

I Would like to open my app from safari, i am new with working with iOS and mobile application development. 
My Website is written in PHP, And i Am Using Objective-c for iOS development.

Comment: refer this link : https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/

Comment: Refer this link : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935987/open-url-schemes-in-ios

Comment: ok thanks mate i have already figured it out. will read up on that even though they are using swift i am sure i could pick up a few tricks or so

Comment: @DhavalRaval thats between two apps, of which i wanted between app and website which will probably be on safari. but thanks anyways

Comment: So are you looking for this? please look into it.. PHP to iOS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750667/php-api-ios-launch-app-from-php-code

Comment: yes something like that @DhavalRaval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ow figured it out was a mistake of not refreshing app
here is an example of switching from browser totally using javascript

```
window.location = "myApp://";
```

This example call app to an iframe so as to preserve the state of the website: still in javascript:

```
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame.src = 'myApp://';
            frame.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(frame);

            // avoid unnecessary iframe on the page

            setTimeout(function() { document.body.removeChild(frame); }, 4);
```

Note that on this examples i have not put any parameters yet which would be like:

```
myApp://params
```

Objective-c End Looks more like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
```

Still have a long way to go but will get there thanks for you help.